# Search value in folder with xlsx files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

I have this code where the user can input a directory and search for value inside all the xlsx files for that specific value.

Let's say that I have a folder with few xlsx I want to search a A-123,
my issue is that it is only working on few occations, it is not working when i write A-123, but works on -123.

Can someone please guide me on what I should do to get it working correctly.
All improvement will be taken with big hearth due to my limited Python experience.

```
from argparse import _CountAction
from itertools import count
from sys import displayhook
import pandas as pd
import os, glob
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook


path = input("Choose directory: ")
number = input("Search for value: ")

print('Searching...')
workbooks = os.listdir(path)
workbooks = [_ for _ in workbooks if not _.startswith('~')]

sheetList3 = []

for workbook in workbooks:
    sheetList2 = []
    ws = load_workbook(os.path.join(path, workbook))
    for sheet_name in (ws.get_sheet_names()):
        sheet = ws.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name) 
        sheetList1 = [] 
        for value in sheet.values:
            if number in " ".join([str(_).lower() for _ in value if _]):
                tuple = (workbook, sheet_name, value)
                sheetList1.append(tuple)

                sheetList2.append(tuple)
                sheetList3.append(tuple)

for count,value in enumerate(sheetList3):
    df=pd.DataFrame(sheetList3)
df.columns = ["Workbook", "Sheet", "Tag"]   

df=pd.DataFrame(sheetList3)
df.to_excel('file.xlsx' , index = False)
```

Comment: What if you try `a-123` ie lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you :) adding .casefold() to the input solved that issue.